# WooCommerce User Registration - Disable state validation for countries with no state

Tags: php, validation, woocommerce

I have added extra registration fields to the WooCommerce registration form. Among these fields are fields for state and country.

This is how I get the state field in the form:

```
$field = [
    'type' => 'state',
    'label' => 'State',
    'required' => 1,
    'class' => ['address-field form-row-first'],
    'validate' => ['state']
];
woocommerce_form_field( 'billing_state', $field, '' );
```

The validation for the state field is done using the following snippet:

```
if (isset($_POST['billing_state']) && empty($_POST['billing_state']) ) { 
    $validation_errors->add('billing_state_error', __('Please enter your State', 'woocommerce')); 
}
```

The validation works fine but I noticed that when a country like Netherlands is chosen, the state field disappears since Netherlands does not have any states. This is ok but when I click on the Sign Up button, the validation for state still runs even though the field is no longer there.

Would anyone know what change I will need to make in order to skip the validation for a field if it is hidden? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would do it:

```php
// Note: I assume the country field's "name" is billing_country. If not, just change it.
$country = wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['billing_country'] ) );
// Here you should do the validation for the selected country...

$states = WC()->countries->get_states( $country );
$state = wc_clean( wp_unslash( $_POST['billing_state'] ) );
if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {
    // There are no states in the selected country, so do nothing.
} elseif ( is_array( $states ) && ! isset( $states[ $state ] ) ) {
    // Either no state was selected or that it's not a valid state.
    $validation_errors->add( 'invalid_billing_state', 'Please select a valid state.' );
} elseif ( empty( $state ) ) {
    // For certain countries such as New Caledonia, state should be manually typed.
    $validation_errors->add( 'empty_billing_state', 'Please enter a valid state.' );
}
```

Reference: [See this file](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/0f28a6191076a57ef6576d9196a863bc79499971/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2713).

Comment: Thank you so much @Sally CJ!! This worked! I was looking at the same file but I had missed out getting the single state out of the array and checking if that was set. I have to wait 20 more hours to be able to award you the bounty. Will do as soon as it becomes active.

Comment: I'm glad it worked and thanks in advance for the bounty! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case you need ti check if that field is hidden or not

```
$(element).is(":hidden");
```

Then remove required from that field

```
$("#billing_state").removeAttr("required");
```

In your case you also need

```
var form = $('#my_form_id').get(0);
$.removeData(form,'validator');
```

Comment: Thanks @Pranav but I was looking for PHP validation. Sorry for not making that clear in my question.